# Unable to output anything.

Tags: c++

I am working on my final project for my c++ class. The instructions are not clear but in either case, I have compiled my code but it won't output anything. Could you please review my code and let me know what I am missing? Here is what she is asking for:

---

This program will include error trapping with try and catch.

Put a throw in each function which gets user input and throw a string "Bad Major" if a Major of 0 is entered. The input functions are specified in 2, 4 and 7 below.

Create a global structure as follows:

```
struct Student 
{ 
       char Name[30]; 
       float GPA; 
       int Major; 
};
```

1. In main create 2 instances of that structure. Call them S1 and S2.
2. Create and call a function named StudentData:
   S2 = StudentData( S1 ); //this is the call to the function
   The function receives as a parameter a reference to the structure (prototyping will handle this) and will return a reference to the structure. Use couts and cins for getting data from the user. For testing purposes, change the data in S1 so that the GPA is 3.5 and the Major is 2. Since you are to use cins for getting data from the user, you are the user and just enter these values. After the call to the function both S1 and S2 will contain the same data.
3. In main print the data stored in the structures S1 and S2 using cout.
4. Call a function named ChangeData with a pointer to S2 as the argument:
           ChangeData( &S2 ); //this is the call to the function
   Change the data in S2 so that the GPA is 3.0 and the Major is 1. (Using these values for testing…)
5. Back in main print the data stored in the structure S2 using cout.
6. Now create an array of 2 structures in main. Call the array Students.
7. Create a function, GetStudents, which will receive the array and an int representing the number of elements(2). In the function, loop through the data and get all three fields from the user using cin, cin.getline and cout statements. Organize like this:

for (...........) 
    { 
    cout prompt to user 
    cin.getline for name 
    cout prompt to user 
    cin for GPA
    cout promp to user
    cin for Major 
    cin.ignore(1); 
    }

The problem is that a cin for a numeric value will leave the ENTER key in the keyboard buffer and that is OK with cin and other numbers but not with strings, thus we must remove it on our own. cin.ignore should handle this for us.

1. Call the function GetStudents from main.
2. Create a function, PrintStudents, which will receive the same arguments as GetStudents. It will print out the array of students on 2 lines, 1 line per student.

Now here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Global variable to determine size of name
const int Name_Size = 30;

//Structure
struct Student
{
    char Name[30];
    float GPA;
    int Major;
};

//Function Prototypes
Student* studentData(Student &S1);
Student* changeData(Student &S2);
Student getStudent(Student array[], int size);
Student printStudents(Student array[], int size);

int main()
{
    Student S1; // structure instance called S1.
    Student S2; // structure instance called S2.

    Student student[2]; //array of 2 structures.

    S2 = *studentData(S1); //Calls the studentData function.

    changeData(S2); //Calls the changeData function.

    getStudent(&S1, 2); //Calls the getStudent function.

    printStudents(&S1, 2); //Calls the printStudents function.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Function Definitions

//studentData function
Student* studentData(Student &S1)
{
        cout << "Student 1" << endl;
        cout << "_________" << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << S1.Name << endl;
        cout << "GPA: " << S1.GPA << endl;
        cout << "Major: " << S1.Major << endl;
        cout << endl;

    if (S1.Major == 0)
    {
        throw "Bad Major!\n";
    }
    else 
        return &S1;
}

Student* changeData(Student &S2)    // Changes the data.
{
        cout << "Name: " << S2.Name << endl;
        cout << "GPA: " << S2.GPA << endl;
        cout << "Major: " << S2.Major << endl;

    if (S2.Major == 0)
    {
        throw "Bad Major!\n";
    }
    else 
        return &S2;     
}

Student getStudent(Student array[], int size) //Function and loop to receive the array and an int representing the number of elements(2). 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter students full name: ";  
        cin.getline(array[index].Name, 30);
        cout << "Please enter students GPA: ";
        cin >> array[index].GPA;
        cout << "Please enter students major: ";
        cin >> array[index].Major;
        cin.ignore(1);
    }
    if (array[1].Major == 0 || array[2].Major == 0)
    {
        throw "Bad Major!\n";
    }
    else
        return array[size];
}

Student printStudents(Student array[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << array[index].Name << "  " << array[index].GPA << "  " << array[index].Major << endl;
        return array[size];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say not showing anything, do you mean that literally, or are you at least seeing some newlines?

Comment: @user1161318 Nothing will output. No newlines or anything. I've looked over this over and over again but can't figure it out. I had a display function but it gave me errors and I didn't really see a need for it so I deleted it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but if I see someone commenting a call to `studentData()` with `//Calls the studentData function.` I would explain once that this is obvious and the comment is to be removed (if this doesn't sink in, I'd try hard to not have this someone on my team). Comments are to explain non-obvious things or interfaces of a component. The only exception are basically automated comments for visual separation of code and copyright statements, etc.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I understand what you are saying but that's what she likes is to put. Even if its simple. I guess its just to show that we will not omit comments. Now as for my questions. I have to make it display in two lines, one per student. However, my code won't display anything even though I have all of my couts. Does this mean that I have to move those to the main function?

Comment: @user1787078 it means you need to 1. read a good C++ introductory book 2. learn to use a debugger. I can't stress this enough. Learning to debug is more important than coding.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - wow, I thought this was a simple question and answer type of thing considering I didn't ask you to do it for me. I asked to review it quickly. I know outputting the info is one of the simplest things to learn about c++. I just can't get it to work. I figured, a simple questions = a simple answer. Obviously I was wrong. Tks anyways.

Comment: @user1787078: If someone implies in an interview that this is how comments are supposed to be (e.g., because it isn't pointed out to be rubbish in an example asking what is wrong with this code), this someone has just reduced the chances to make it through the interview a bit (admittedly, most of the time the reasons people don't make it through an interview are a lot deeper than that, though).

Comment: @user1787078 You're thinking about [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). [SO] is for specific questions. You can't just paste a wall of code and expect us to debug. Have you tried debugging yourself? If you had, you'd have narrowed it down by now.

Comment: To further emphasize what Luchian is saying: The posted code actually does print things for me. It's junk but this is what I expected. Your description of not printing anything, thus, doesn't match the problem.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thankfully, I am not trying to interview right now nor was my question related to my comments. Thanks for letting me know that my code works for your even thought is "Junk" for you. I truly appreciate the love. But I have a program to fix and 2 test to take by midnight so needless to say I don't have time to sit here and take lessons for someone who likes to step on those like me "New and trying to learn something from the pros". Thank you mucho anyhow.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - I didn't know about codereview. Thanks. I thought based on what i read about your site that this is what stackoverflow is for. I have used my debugger and it has given me errors that I did fix. This one however doesn't come up as an error, it just runs and doesn't output anything. But like I told the other guy. I don't have time to try to defend myself. I either get help or not. Its too bad I can't get it from the pros.

Comment: @user1787078 we are helping. A debugger doesn't show errors. You're thinking about a compiler. A debugger allows you to step through the code and see what it does. **"Use a debugger!"** is the best possible advice you can get at this point.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore please don't insult my intelligence. I know what a debugger is. Like I said, my program runs fine. It just doesn't stop to output. So no, you are not helping.

Comment: @user1787078: I didn't say you *code* is junk, I said the output is junk. Which is expected because the initial version of your object isn't initialized and, thus, contains whatever random bytes (i.e. junk) was in the memory location. Also, if you can't describe your problem (which clearly is not that there is no output because there is output) there is little we can do to help!

Comment: "I have used my debugger and it has given me errors that I did fix. This one however doesn't come up as an error" pray tell how a debugger showed you errors that you fixed? I'd like to get my hands on a debugger that smart. Mine just allows me to step through the code, but it never says "hey, dumbass, there's an error right here!"

Comment: When you say "it doesn't stop for output" do you mean a window show up and disappears because you can see what's being output? That would be a hint on what's actually wrong... Try reading some input, e.g. after catching your exception: `std::cin >> std::ws;` (or whatever). Of course, you'd need to put a `try { ... } catch (std::exception const& ex) { ... }` block around your code and your error handling.

Comment: I've got it. You guys could have saved all of us the time by just making me aware that "hey, I was missing the try/catch blocks". Seriously, just bc you sit behind closed doors in a computer doesn't mean you can be mean to others. Every time i come here for help I waste a good hour of my time and yours arguing about what I am posting. Seriously, save the time. I didn't ask you to do it for me. all you had to say was "you forgot ...." Not "dumb person, you arent doing it right and you don't know what you are doing and your class and book suck".

Comment: @user1787078: Given that your code printed something for me (and probably for Luchian) it wasn't clear what you are asking. Only when you said "it doesn't stop to output" it transpired to me that you may have a window closing before you can see the output. If you had stated this directly, I wouldn't have looked why your output might go wrong but would have looked why it immediately terminates (... and working from within the shell, I see the output anyway and it isn't natural for me that output windows just disappear again). I'd think you need to better describe your problem!

Comment: @user1787078 this is a community. A community has rules. Never once was anyone mean to you. Though you deserve it, by not following the rules. You got advice and chose to ignore it. When I said "use a debugger", I said it because it would help **you**. Not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Review your syntax for calling functions:</s>

```
S2 = *studentData(S1);
```

I believe functions are called without the '*':

```
S2 = studentData(S1);
```

There may be more like this in your program.

### Edit1: Passing by reference, returning pointer to passed reference

On further inspection of your program, the function `studentData` receives a `Student` variable **passed by reference**.  This means that the original variable passed to this function can be modified directly.  At the end of the function, you return a pointer to this variable.  Kind of redundant.

Similarly with `changeData()`.

Also, **per requirement #2**, the function `StudentData` needs to return a reference not a pointer.  The declaration would look like:

```
Student& StudentData(Student& any_student);
```

**Note the spelling of the function per requirement.**

Comment: I changed it but i continue to get red under the = sign. why?

Comment: Some questions to think about:  You are passing a student by reference, which means you can directly modify the variable passed.  So, why are you returning a pointer to this variable?  You don't *need* to return variables if you pass them by reference.